# Starship Troopers Choose Your Own Adventure with RPG aspects

Tags: story-identification, robert-a-heinlein, starship-troopers

I read this in the late eighties. It was official Starship Troopers branded, based entirely on the book, not the movie. Unlike a traditional Choose Your Own Adventure, in this you had units, statistics, and lookup tables at the back of the book that determined how much damage you took, like an RNG in a video game. To be clear, this was a book, not an RPG manual. Book-length, thicker than a traditional Choose Your Own Adventure. On certain pages, your progress was determined by the outcome of a battle, instead of just reading and choosing. These pages would have maps on them, and units that survived would get bonuses for future battles.

I learned the word Ordnance from this book because that was your heavy weapons capability. You could gain units of it and carry them over from battle to battle. I remember one page being a map where you could decide to put your troopers in one or another zone to listen for Bugs crackling, based on whether you thought they would come down an underground highway or up out of a crater. Then each zone had a number to tell you which page you should turn to. I believe that page would tell you how well your strategy worked out and how that affected your starting strength in the main battle, then send you on to the battle map page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After writing up the entire question, I clicked a related question about a Star Trek Choose Your Own Adventure and found Hypnosifl's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139913/20953) pointing me to [gamebooks.org](https://gamebooks.org/). It was *Robert Heinlein's Starship Troopers: Shines the Name*.

Comment: There's a 2-day waiting period to accept your own answer in case someone comes along with a better or more complete one.

Comment: I didn't know if you were familiar with that option _at all_, but apparently you are. Carry on, then. :)