# Do transportees experience the passage of time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-transporter

In Star Trek when one is transported, does it feel instantaneous regardless of if there is a need to store the person's pattern in the pattern buffer for any length of time?  Is the sensation of transport instantaneous regardless of length of time between dematerialization and rematerialization?

**NOTE:** *This answer is probably going to have to come from the expanded Star Trek media (prose novels, comics, etc.) as we don't really get a first person perspective from the shows/movies during transportation.*

Comment: Mark Twain wears a watch while being transported. But I doubt it has sufficient precision to measure if time has passed for it or not.

Comment: There's two different questions here - 1) What is people's perception of transport and 2) Is transport instantaneous?

Comment: @Richard apologies for the confusion, my focus of the question is if the sensation of transport is instantaneous regardless of time between dematerialization and rematerialization.

Comment: In which case the question needs rewording.

Comment: @Richard I have removed the portion dealing with the watch as that's an objective observation and I'm looking for more of a subjective one.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the question title

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does a person's sense of self arrive when beamed?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44781/when-does-a-persons-sense-of-self-arrive-when-beamed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, while transporting you have no perception of time. This is why [Scotty still thought Kirk came to rescue him](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relics_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29) when he actually spent 75 years in the transporter buffer.

> **RIKER:** I'm Commander William Riker, starship Enterprise. Lieutenant Commander Geordi La Forge.
>
> **SCOTT:** The Enterprise? I should have known. I bet Jim Kirk himself hauled the old girl out of mothballs to come looking for me. Captain Montgomery Scott. Tell me, how long have I been missing?

However, we get some insights in how it is to be transported. In ["Realm of fear"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Realm_of_Fear_%28episode%29) the camera "witnesses" the moment of de-materialization:

[image]

In that episode, Barcley finds some of the survivors of the USS Yosemite "parked" in the transporter in a similar way Scotty saved himself 75 years before.

Comment: This doesn't address the question of time dilation

Comment: @Richard True. The way I read the question, it was only about the _perception_ of time. And my answer is (in a nutshell): You don't have any. I just didn't read the _objectively instantaneous / beam takes time to travel_ part into the question.

Comment: My issue with this answer is that human perception of time is very poor. Anything that takes less than .01 milisecond basically falls below our level of perception.

Comment: Time dilation and the perception of time is the same thing. There is no perception of time, no time dilation. There can't be since all the mass is converted into an energy beam and if there is no mass, there can't be any time dilation.

Comment: @Sulthan - They are most certainly not the same thing. You and are are almost certainly experiencing differing amounts of time dilation right now, due to our relative positions on Earth. Just because something is imperceptible to a human doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Richard The op uses the words "_experienced_" and "_feel_ instantaneous". On those words I focused my answer. But I think you are right that a different interpretation of the question is _possible_. Maybe Monty129 should clarify that.

Comment: @Einer et. all, I've edited the question, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: In Scotty's case it may be that an extended stay in the transporter system causes short term confusion, since Scotty was present on the Enterprise B when Kirk was lost to the Nexus, and should have known that Kirk couldn't have came to rescue him.